# Proof of a lemma is unclear to me (Theorem of inverse functions)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, functions, differential-topology

Lemma: Let $B(a,r)$ be a ball in Banach space $X$ and $\phi$ be a contraction ($d(\phi(x),\phi(y)\leq qd(x,y),0<q<1$) from $B(a,r)\to X $. Then the function:$$ f(x)=x+\phi(x)$$ is a homeomorphism some open set $U$ from $B(a,r)$ to $B(f(a),(1-q)r)$.

Now a homeomorphism is a bijective function that is continuous and it's inverse is continous. We need to prove this. The proof starts:
(Since it's a Banach space the metric is defined by the norm)
$$d(f(x),f(y))=\|f(x)-f(y)\|=\|x+\phi(x)-y-\phi(y)\|\geq \|x-y\|-\|\phi(x)-\phi(y)\|\geq(1-q)\|x-y\|\implies$$"Injective". Here $\|a+b\|\geq\|a\|-\|b\|$ is used.
We have to prove $y \in B(f(a),B(1-q)r)$
$f(x)=y, y=x+\phi(x),x=y-\phi(x)$ lets have a function: $g_y(t)=y-\phi(t)$ then$ \|g_y(t)-g_y(s)\|\leq q(t-s)$ we have to show: $g_y(B(a,r))\subseteq B(a,r);z\in g_y(B(a,r))\implies g_y(t)=z, t\in B(a,r). z=y-\phi(t);$ $$d(z,a)=\|y-\phi(t)-a\|=\|y-\phi(a)-a+\phi(a)-\phi(t)\|\leq \| y-f(a)\|+\|\phi(a)-\phi(t)\|<(1-q)r+qr=r $$aka $d(z,a)<r\implies z\in B(a,r)$.. I can type out the rest of the proof if need be. What is unclear to me is one of the last inqualities :$\|y-f(a)\|\leq(1-q)r ??$

Comment: could you please some more structure? It's hard to figure out what is given and what you seek.

Comment: just the last inequality is unclear f(a)=a+ϕ(a) and ∥f(x)−f(a)∥≤(1−q)r is used i don't know how this is possible..

Comment: ∥f(x)−f(y)∥≥(1−q)∥x−y∥ might be useful

Comment: It is a bit confusing!! You want to prove something you use. I will prove the lemma and post it as an answer to your question

Comment: That's what I thought exactly but am thinking is it at all possible that i can't see why ∥y−f(a)∥≤(1−q)r

Comment: I'll ask my professor tomorrow. Don't answer the lemma quite yet. I'll provide a proof of the full theorem, which i don't completely understand tomorrow with a bounty of 75.

Comment: Please  fix the grammar and separate the steps into discrete sentences and state what each step is.

Comment: I cleared this up, thanks for the advice though.