# Help with contraction function in balls

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

A contraction is a function $f:X\to Y$ that satisfies:$$d(f(x),f(y))\leq  qd(x,y);0<q<1$$ Now if we have a ball $B(a,r)$ and a contraction $f:X \to X$ Then the necessary condition for the contraction to map the given ball into the same ball again is $$d(f(a),a)\leq(1-q)r$$the center moves less than $(1-q)r$, Why??

Comment: Add a upvote so the question becomes relevent to viewers :D

Comment: I think people (not me) downvoted your question for some other reason... Not that I would know. But I'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean sufficient condition. Write :
$$ f(x)-a=f(x)-f(a)+f(a)-a$$
and use the triangular inequality.

Comment: Not quite, i believe.

Comment: What do you mean ? You marked an identical answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x\in B(a,r)$ we have $$d(a,f(x))\leq d(a,f(a))+d(f(a),f(x))$$ So if $d(a,f(a))\leq (1-q)r$ and taking into account that $f$ is a contraction i.e $d(f(a),f(x))\leq d(a,x)$ we have $$\begin{align} d(a,f(x)) 
&\leq (1-q)r+qd(a,x)\\
&\leq (1-q)r+qr\\
&=r
\end{align}$$ and this means $f(x)\in B(a,r)$
The condition is sufficient

Comment: Can i have you look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148252/proof-of-a-lemma-is-unclear-to-me-theorem-of-inverse-functions i'll offer you 50 rep, answer here and again tomorrow there and you'll have it, it means a lot to me.

Comment: I will have a look